# Android - How to get from string resources all the elements which contains two or more similar words on their names

Tags: java, android, string, resources

I am looking about using the Android's resources and i want to get for example from the strings.xml file all the elements that include the word "menu", all of this is for managing the multiple section translations.

My XML is this

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
<string name="usage_analytics">Show Analytics</string>
<string name="option_resume">Resume</string>
<string name="option_analisys">Analysis</string>
<string name="option_categories">Categories</string>
<string name="option_settings">Settings</string>
```

and for this i want to get all the elements that contain the "option" word in their name. In my example i want to get option_resume, option_analysis, option_categories and option_settings

In this case i have found advise to make it manually, like GetString(R.string.option_resume), GetString(R.string.option_analisys), GetString(R.string.option_categories), GetString(R.string.option_settings), etc

But for this case i have to make it dynamically obtaining all the items which have a determined word and without a String array resource.

So any idea for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But for this case i have to make it dinamically obtaining all the items which have a determinated word

You do not need to do it dynamically. The resources are known at compile time. A new set of resources will not appear magically in your app with a new prefix.

> without a String array resource

A `string-array` resource would be the sensible way of doing it. I am not quite certain why you do not wish to use it. Given your existing `strings.xml` from above, have an `arrays.xml` with:

```
<string-array name="options">
  <string>@string/option_resume</string>
  <string>@string/option_analisys</string>
  <string>@string/option_categories</string>
  <string>@string/option_settings</string>
</string-array>
```

Then, requesting the `options` string array at runtime will give you the desired strings.

If your concern is manually maintaining that `arrays.xml` file, write yourself a bit of code to generate it as part of your build (e.g., custom Gradle task, custom Gradle plugin).

The slow and sloppy way of doing this would be to use Java reflection to iterate over all `R.string` fields for your app's `R` class, find their names, see which ones match, then use `getString()` to get the corresponding string values.

Comment: That was the answer, thanks a lot. And like you say, in this case like , we can make reference to specific string we can have it on the arrays resouce. That was my error, because i was not making reference.
And i had the wrong idea to take it with a loop from all the resources, making it slowlier, in that case

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with help of @CommonsWare

```
String[] optionsArray = ctx.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.option_strings);
```

And using that, i made the action i was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
 private String getData(String suffix){

        String data = "option" + suffix;

        String getStringData = this.getResources().getString(
                this.getResources().getIdentifier(data, Const.STRING,
                        this.getPackageName()));

        return getStringData ; 
    }
```

call this Function and u will get a Specific string. and if u need a list of string then u can use in the loop.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, how this answers the question. The OP does not know the value of `lookingFor` as **that is what the OP is trying to find**.

Comment: That does not return a List or array. He wants to find ALL Strings with "option" in it.

Comment: Updated Ans. please check now.

Comment: That does not help at all.

Comment: @Prexx that is correct, because in that example it returns a string only and it is not te required way. I would think on a loop there, but the problem here is to find the way to get a String Resource List, and iterate into it